# How to change lightbulb inside a fixture

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, light

I want to change this burnt out light:

[image]

How can I get at it to change it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should unscrew counterclockwise if you put friction on the inner chrome ring with your fingertips.

If it does not unscrew, you can pull the whole thing out of the receiver by using your fingernails on the outermost edges and pulling down. You can then inspect it for how to remove the lamp.

Comment: The paint can openers they hand out at places like Lowes and Home Depot are great for this purpose. I used one myself when changing the bulbs in a similar fixture.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar light fixtures in my house.  When I bought the light fixtures they came with a small suction cup that you place on the bulb and turn it.